# как в laravel 5.4 задать алиас для таблицы

Tags: laravel, eloquent, alias

Подскажите, 
как в  laravel 5.4 задать алиас для таблицы чтобы потом его использовать в ->select? Делаю:

```
$quoteModel->from( ' category as '.\DB::raw('cat') );
```

...
    $quoteModel->select(  \DB::raw('cat.name ')  );
    $categoriesList= $quoteModel->paginate($items_per_page);

И получаю ошибку :

```
select cat.name from "pd_category" as "pd_cat" order by "name" asc limit 20 offset 0
```

pd_ - это префикс в настройках.
Спасибо!

Comment: просто напиши без DB::raw

Comment: Такой синтаксис нормально работает если работать с таблицами
    DB::table('category AS cat')  ->select('cat.name AS cat_name')     ->get();

Но при работе с моделями 
    $res= $quoteModel->from( $table_name.' as cat' )->select( 'cat.name as cat_name'  )  ->get();

Получаю ошибку при написании алиаса :

    select cat.name from "pd_category" as "pd_cat" order by "name" asc limit 20 offset 0

а как правильно?

Comment: А тут наверное в select как раз нужен DB::raw по-моему, но не уверен

Comment: Пробовал и так, и так - не помогает.

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос, приведи более полный пример, что б можно было повторить, прям весь листинг, выборки, попробую повторить

Answer (score 0):

Поковырявшись, удалось запустить так(у меня там небольшой конструктор - так как в зависимости от входных параметров могут меняться параметры запроса):

```
$category_table_name= with(new Category)->getTableName();
$quoteModel= Category::from(  \DB::raw(DB::getTablePrefix().$category_table_name.' as cat' ));

$additive_fields_for_select= "";
$fields_for_select= 'cat.*';

$product_category_table_name= DB::getTablePrefix().'product_category';
if ( !empty($filtersArray['show_products_count']) ) {
    $additive_fields_for_select .= ', ( select count(*) from ' . $product_category_table_name . ' as pc where pc.category_id = ' . 'cat.id ) as category_products_count';
}

$fields_for_select.= ' ' . $additive_fields_for_select;
$quoteModel->select( \DB::raw($fields_for_select) );
$categoriesList= $quoteModel->paginate($items_per_page);
```

И генерит такой sql:

```
select cat.* , ( select count(*) from pd_product_category as pc where pc.category_id = cat.id ) as category_products_count from pd_category as cat order by "name" asc limit 20 offset 0
```

Comment: А смысл делать столько шагов если можно просто предать алиас ?

Answer (score 0):

**Для чего предназначены**  [**DB::raw**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Иногда вам может понадобиться использовать необработанное выражение в запросе. Эти выражения будут вставляться в запрос как строки, поэтому будьте осторожны, чтобы не создавать никаких точек инъекции SQL! Чтобы создать необработанное выражение, вы можете использовать метод **DB :: raw**:

**А ваш вопрос можно решить просто:**

Добавить алиас в ручную:

```
$quoteModel->from( 'category cat');
```

И пользоваться им:

```
... $quoteModel->select( 'cat.name' ); 
$categoriesList= $quoteModel->paginate($items_per_page);
```